# mulitple loop for reading bands in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

i want to read separate table from images in python. i have 10 images (b1,b2,b3....b10) with 8 bands in which I have to proceed this functions

```
b1 = rasterio.open('B1.tif')
b2 = rasterio.open('B2.tif')
b3 = rasterio.open('B3.tif')
...
b10 = rasterio.open('B10.tif')
```

I started to try this with just one loop and the update. but this error appears

```
b1 = rasterio.open('B1.tif')
for i in range(1,8):
    b1_(i) = b1.read(i)
 File "<ipython-input-4-c7fe8df05d17>", line 3
    b1_(i) = b1.read(i)
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried?  Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem.  It may be helpful to you to read the [SO guide to asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you assume, that the python interpreter will resolve `b1_(i)` to e.g. `b1_10` if `i` equals 10 in that loop. That however is not part of the python language definition. In fact, and as the error states, this syntax looks like a function invocation to the interpreter (of the function `b1_` with argument `i`).

For your code to be able to be interpretet, (but be aware, this is a bad habit of coding and I will suggest a possible solution below,) you could replace `b1_(i) = b1.read(i)` by `eval("b1_"+str(i)+"b1.read("+str(i)+")")`. `eval` is a function, which takes a string and evaluates it as a line of code.

As mentioned, this is bad coding style. Code using `eval` is much harder to read, as this simple example should already sufficiently show. Furthermore, `eval` is in some situations susceptible to code injection, which may lead to security issues. (Especially, if eval is used to execute a piece of code, which contains data entered from a user, who could use this fact to inject malicious code on his own.) There are also other issues, but to discuss that further would unnessesarily bloat this answer; you may consider doing some research on yourself here.

So how to do it right? The best way would be to use an array of values instead of many different variables. You can do that in python like this:

```
fp_b1 = rasterio.open('B1.tif')
store_b1 = []
for i in range(1,9):
    store_b1[i] = fp_b1.read(i)
```

Note, that I had also to change the parameters of range, since range will not include stop.

As array generally start with index 0 in python (and many other programming languages), this code would probably be written rather like this:

```
fp_b1 = rasterio.open('B1.tif')
store_b1 = []
for i in range(8):
    store_b1[i] = fp_b1.read(i+1)
```